# Ask for two objects in -if- statement without specify the question in the second object

Tags: python

I wanna know if there is a way to check for two objects without using the -or- operator, or using it but without the declaration. Here's the example

```
if x == y or x == z:
```

Instead of that, I would like to do something like

```
if x == y or z:
```

Is there any way to do that? Maybe using an array? Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `if x == y or x == z:` is not good enough?

Comment: I guess you can do `if x in (y, z):`

Comment: Hey dm2, yes there is a reason, I wanna make a group of users who will have the authority to do something, but instead of adding them one by one, I would like to just make a group of them, and then calling them

Comment: Alright Rocket, thanks (that just helped me a lot for another issue I was having)

Answer (score 1):

You cold try doing something like:

```
if x in [z, y]:
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason not to use `if x == y or x == z:`, but if you have multiple values to compare,  then the code just gets longer, and in that case, `in` operator becomes handy to use:

```py
if a in {w,x,y,z}: # equivalent to a==w or a==x or a==y or a==z
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Ohhh, thank you! I didn't know about that operator, Ill search about it